trilateration algorithm for calculation of real time location (flutter app) (BLE beacons used)
I am trying to implement a real-time location system in which I can upload a map (image) and pinpoint certain things such as the location of beacons, destination, and so on. I am trying to calculate the offset of the user's current location using trilateration algorithm with usage of 3 BLE beacons. I get the user's offset position (I am not sure if it is correct if could you help me check the code to calculate the offset). I get the numbers from Trilaterated Position but whenever I try to Normalized Position to meet the bounds of the 1.0x1.0 area I always get Offset(0.0, 0.0).
The output:Image of the map
I/flutter (26855): Calculated distance for RSSI -51: 0.042142603378185865 meters
I/flutter (26855): Calculated distance for RSSI -82: 3.158131786557508 meters
I/flutter (26855): Calculated distance for RSSI -86: 4.510052575551847 meters
I/flutter (26855): Calculated distance for RSSI -51: 0.042142603378185865 meters
I/flutter (26855): Beacon Positions: [Offset(0.1, 0.2), Offset(0.9, 0.4), Offset(0.7, 0.7)]
I/flutter (26855): Distances: [0.042142603378185865, 3.158131786557508, 4.510052575551847]
I/flutter (26855): Performing trilateration
I/flutter (26855): Trilaterated Position: Offset(-1.7111844855867229, -17.85240513002308)
I/flutter (26855): Normalized Position: Offset(0.0, 0.0)
I/flutter (26855): Updated Position: Offset(0.0, 0.0)
ble controller.dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class BleController extends GetxController {
  final FlutterBlue _flutterBlue = FlutterBlue.instance;
  final _scanResults = <ScanResult>[].obs;
  final _currentPosition = Offset(0.0, 0.0).obs;
  final _isScanning = false.obs;
  final _updateTimer = Rx<Timer?>(null);
  Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>> _beaconsData = {};

  RxList<ScanResult> get scanResults => _scanResults;
  Offset get currentPosition => _currentPosition.value;
  bool get isScanning => _isScanning.value;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    print('BleController initialized');
    _fetchBeaconsData().then((_) {
      print('Beacons data fetched');
      startScanning();
    }).catchError((error) {
      print('Error fetching beacons data: $error');
    });

    _flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((results) {
      _scanResults.assignAll(results);
      print('Scan results updated: $results');
    });

    _updateTimer.value = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      _updatePosition();
    });
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    _updateTimer.value?.cancel();
    _flutterBlue.stopScan();
    super.onClose();
  }

  Future<void> _fetchBeaconsData() async {
    print('Fetching beacons data from Firestore');
    final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    final snapshot = await firestore.collection('maps').get();
    _beaconsData = {};

    for (var doc in snapshot.docs) {
      var pinpoints = doc.data()['pinpoints'] as List<dynamic>;
      for (var point in pinpoints) {
        if (point['type'] == 'beacon') {
          _beaconsData[point['beaconId']] = {
            'dx': point['dx'],
            'dy': point['dy']
          };
        }
      }
    }

    print('Beacons Data: $_beaconsData');
  }

  Future<void> startScanning() async {
    if (!_isScanning.value) {
      _scanResults.clear();
      _isScanning.value = true;
      await _flutterBlue.startScan(
          timeout: Duration(hours: 1)); // Long scan duration
      print('Started scanning');
    }
  }

  Future<void> stopScanning() async {
    if (_isScanning.value) {
      await _flutterBlue.stopScan();
      _isScanning.value = false;
      print('Stopped scanning');
    }
  }

  double calculateDistance(int rssi) {
    int txPower = -70; // Default value for most BLE devices
    if (rssi == 0) {
      print('RSSI is 0, returning -1');
      return -1.0; // If we cannot determine distance, return -1.
    }

    double ratio = rssi * 1.0 / txPower;
    double distance;

    if (ratio < 1.0) {
      distance = pow(ratio, 10).toDouble();
    } else {
      distance = (0.89976) * pow(ratio, 7.7095) + 0.111;
    }

    print('Calculated distance for RSSI $rssi: $distance meters');
    return distance;
  }

  void startTracking() {
    startScanning();
    print('Started tracking');
  }

  void stopTracking() {
    stopScanning();
    _updateTimer.value?.cancel();
    print('Stopped tracking');
  }

  void _updatePosition() {
    var beacons = _scanResults
        .where((result) => _beaconsData.containsKey(result.device.id.id))
        .toList();

    print('Filtered beacons: $beacons');

    if (beacons.length >= 3) {
      _currentPosition.value = calculatePosition(beacons);
      print('Updated Position: ${_currentPosition.value}');
    } else {
      print('Not enough beacons found for trilateration');
    }

    print('Scan results: $_scanResults');
    print('Current Position: ${_currentPosition.value}');
  }

  Offset calculatePosition(List<ScanResult> beacons) {
    beacons.sort((a, b) =>
        calculateDistance(a.rssi).compareTo(calculateDistance(b.rssi)));

    var closestBeacons = beacons.take(3).toList();
    var distances = closestBeacons
        .map((b) => calculateDistance(b.rssi).toDouble())
        .toList();
    var beaconPositions = closestBeacons
        .map((b) {
          var data = _beaconsData[b.device.id.id];
          if (data != null && data['dx'] != null && data['dy'] != null) {
            return Offset(
                (data['dx'] as num).toDouble(), (data['dy'] as num).toDouble());
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        })
        .where((position) => position != null)
        .toList()
        .cast<Offset>();

    if (beaconPositions.length < 3) {
      print('Not enough valid beacon positions for trilateration');
      return Offset(0.0, 0.0);
    }

    print('Beacon Positions: $beaconPositions');
    print('Distances: $distances');

    return normalizePosition(trilaterate(beaconPositions, distances));
  }

  Offset trilaterate(List<Offset> positions, List<double> distances) {
    print('Performing trilateration');
    double x1 = positions[0].dx, y1 = positions[0].dy, r1 = distances[0];
    double x2 = positions[1].dx, y2 = positions[1].dy, r2 = distances[1];
    double x3 = positions[2].dx, y3 = positions[2].dy, r3 = distances[2];

    double A = 2 * x2 - 2 * x1;
    double B = 2 * y2 - 2 * y1;
    double C = (pow(r1, 2) -
            pow(r2, 2) -
            pow(x1, 2) +
            pow(x2, 2) -
            pow(y1, 2) +
            pow(y2, 2))
        .toDouble();
    double D = 2 * x3 - 2 * x2;
    double E = 2 * y3 - 2 * y2;
    double F = (pow(r2, 2) -
            pow(r3, 2) -
            pow(x2, 2) +
            pow(x3, 2) -
            pow(y2, 2) +
            pow(y3, 2))
        .toDouble();

    double x = (C * E - F * B) / (E * A - B * D);
    double y = (C * D - A * F) / (B * D - A * E);

    print('Trilaterated Position: Offset($x, $y)');

    return Offset(x, y);
  }

  Offset normalizePosition(Offset position) {
    // Get the min and max bounds of the beacons
    double minX =
        _beaconsData.values.map((data) => data['dx'] as double).reduce(min);
    double maxX =
        _beaconsData.values.map((data) => data['dx'] as double).reduce(max);
    double minY =
        _beaconsData.values.map((data) => data['dy'] as double).reduce(min);
    double maxY =
        _beaconsData.values.map((data) => data['dy'] as double).reduce(max);

    // Normalize the position to the image bounds
    double normalizedX = ((position.dx - minX) / (maxX - minX)).clamp(0.0, 1.0);
    double normalizedY = ((position.dy - minY) / (maxY - minY)).clamp(0.0, 1.0);

    print('Normalized Position: Offset($normalizedX, $normalizedY)');

    return Offset(normalizedX, normalizedY);
  }
}

Map detail screen.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'ble_controller.dart';

class MapDetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String imageUrl;
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> pinpoints;
  final String? initialCurrentLocation;

  const MapDetailScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.pinpoints,
    this.initialCurrentLocation,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MapDetailScreenState createState() => _MapDetailScreenState();
}

class _MapDetailScreenState extends State<MapDetailScreen> {
  String? _currentLocation;
  String? _destination;
  Offset _currentPosition = Offset(0.0, 0.0);
  bool _isTracking = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _currentLocation = widget.initialCurrentLocation;
    if (_currentLocation != null) {
      var initialPinpoint = widget.pinpoints.firstWhere(
          (pinpoint) => pinpoint['name'] == _currentLocation,
          orElse: () => {});
      if (initialPinpoint.isNotEmpty) {
        _currentPosition = Offset(
          initialPinpoint['dx'] as double,
          initialPinpoint['dy'] as double,
        );
        _startTracking();
      }
    }
  }

  void _startTracking() {
    setState(() {
      _isTracking = true;
      Get.find<BleController>().startTracking();
    });
  }

  void _stopTracking() {
    setState(() {
      _isTracking = false;
      Get.find<BleController>().stopTracking();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    Get.find<BleController>().stopTracking();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Map Detail'),
        actions: [
          if (_isTracking)
            TextButton(
              onPressed: _stopTracking,
              child: Text(
                'Stop Tracking',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                DropdownButton<String>(
                  hint: Text('Current Location'),
                  value: _currentLocation,
                  items: widget.pinpoints.map((pinpoint) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: pinpoint['name'],
                      child: Text(pinpoint['name']),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _currentLocation = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                DropdownButton<String>(
                  hint: Text('Destination'),
                  value: _destination,
                  items: widget.pinpoints.map((pinpoint) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: pinpoint['name'],
                      child: Text(pinpoint['name']),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _destination = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (context, constraints) {
                return Stack(
                  children: [
                    InteractiveViewer(
                      minScale: 0.1,
                      maxScale: 4.0,
                      child: Image.network(
                        widget.imageUrl,
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        width: constraints.maxWidth,
                        height: constraints.maxHeight,
                      ),
                    ),
                    ...widget.pinpoints.map((pinpoint) {
                      var dx = pinpoint['dx'] as double;
                      var dy = pinpoint['dy'] as double;
                      IconData iconData;
                      Color iconColor;

                      switch (pinpoint['type']) {
                        case 'location':
                          iconData = Icons.place;
                          iconColor = Colors.blue;
                          break;
                        case 'qrCode':
                          iconData = Icons.qr_code;
                          iconColor = Colors.green;
                          break;
                        default:
                          iconData = Icons.location_on;
                          iconColor = Colors.red;
                      }

                      return Positioned(
                        left: dx * constraints.maxWidth,
                        top: dy * constraints.maxHeight,
                        child: Icon(
                          iconData,
                          color: iconColor,
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    if (_isTracking)
                      Obx(() {
                        var bleController = Get.find<BleController>();
                        var livePosition = bleController.currentPosition;
                        print('Updated Position: $livePosition');
                        return Positioned(
                          left: livePosition.dx * constraints.maxWidth,
                          top: livePosition.dy * constraints.maxHeight,
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.person_pin_circle,
                            color: Colors.purple,
                          ),
                        );
                      }),
                    if (!_isTracking)
                      Positioned(
                        left: _currentPosition.dx * constraints.maxWidth,
                        top: _currentPosition.dy * constraints.maxHeight,
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.person_pin_circle,
                          color: Colors.purple,
                        ),
                      ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Select map screen.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'map_detail_screen.dart';

class SelectMapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SelectMapScreen({super.key});

  @override
  _SelectMapScreenState createState() => _SelectMapScreenState();
}

class _SelectMapScreenState extends State<SelectMapScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Select Map'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('maps').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }

          var maps = snapshot.data!.docs;

          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: maps.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              var map = maps[index];
              var imageUrl = map['imageUrl'];
              var pinpoints = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(map['pinpoints']);

              return ListTile(
                title: Text('Map ${index + 1}'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => MapDetailScreen(
                        imageUrl: imageUrl,
                        pinpoints: pinpoints,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

I would appreciate any suggestion on how I can solve the problem, or for the solution itself. Thank you very much for considering the problem.
